# Missing parts of graphics on LyX

Tags: graphics, eps, wolfram-mathematica

I am exporting some images from Mathematica 11 as EPS images and use them on LyX. [image]

Here is an example. It should be normally c(t,b). Here is the all code that I use for preambule of LateX.

```
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\onehalfspacing
\makeatletter
\def\@makefnmark{%
\leavevmode
\raise.9ex\hbox{\fontsize\sf@size\z@\normalfont\tiny\@thefnmark}}
\makeatother

\newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}[section]
\newtheorem{Proposition}{Proposition}
\newtheorem{Definition}{Definition}
\newtheorem{lem}[thm]{Lemma}
\newtheorem{cor}[thm]{Corollary}
\hypersetup{pdfstartview={FitH}}
\DeclareTextCommandDefault{\texteuro}
{\CheckEncodingSubset\UseTextSymbol{TS1}\tc@fake@euro5\texteuro}
```

I already checked that there is no missing part of images when I open the EPS files after exporting it from Mathematica 11. However, it starts to have missing parts once I put them on LyX.

Is there something I am missing ?

Comment: Can you export PDF from Mathematica, and use that instead of EPS?

Comment: @TorbjørnT. I tried this as well. Not only there are missing parts but also the quality of graphics decreases as well... I tried the same procedures on another computer and the same thing happens. I wonder whether it is a bug on Mathematica 11 because I did not have this issue on earlier versions of Mathematica.

Comment: Not sure I have much to contribute here. I would guess that there is some problem with the fonts, but I don't know how they're handled in EPS-files. I don't have any experience at all with Mathematica either. Can you upload the EPS-file somewhere (e.g. Dropbox, it can't be uploaded here on site), so others can test with it?

Comment: For sure. Here is the link ; 

https://www.dropbox.com/s/cffrkyo7aj2xiz3/intragen%20high%20risk.eps?dl=0

Comment: Hm. That worked fine here. Try this PDF: https://www.dropbox.com/s/4mo7v4ef2modrhl/intragen.pdf?dl=0

Comment: Cool ! That worked thanks ! Did you do something special ?

Comment: No, just converted the EPS with `epstopdf`. It's a bit strange that it worked, because `epstopdf` is what is normally used to convert EPS to PDF, but I guess the main point is that it did work.